# A problem to be solved using integration by parts.

Tags: calculus, integration

Assume all functions of the form $(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$. Given that
$$
f(x) - \lambda_1 f''(x) = 0
$$
and
$$
g(x) - \lambda_2 g''(x) = 0,
$$
for all $x \in (0,1)$.

Also, $$
f(0) = f(1),\qquad f'(0) = f'(1),\qquad g(0) = g(1),\qquad g'(0) = g'(1).
$$

Prove using integration by parts, that 
$$
\int_0^1 f(x)g(x) dx = 0
$$
when $\lambda_1 \ne \lambda_2$.

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: @AndrewLi : I am going in a loop arriving where I started. I am using integration by parts to capitalize on the given conditions.

Comment: I want to prove using only integration by parts. I want to do without  explicitly solving those ODE's.

Comment: "going in a loop" sounds like you integrated by parts, switched your $u$ and $v$, and the integrated by parts again.  Whenever you do that, you'll always go in a loop and arrive back where you started.  The trick in those situations is to press on with the second integration by parts.

Answer (score 6):

You just have to do integration by parts twice.

Let $I=\int f(x)g(x)dx$

The first by parts with $u=f(x)$ and $v'=g(x)=\lambda_2g''(x)$ gives 
$$I=\lambda_2f(x)g'(x)-\int\lambda_2f'(x)g'(x)dx$$

Then by parts again with $u=f'(x)\implies u'=\frac{1}{\lambda_1}f(x)$ and $v'=g'(x)$ gives $$I=\lambda_2f(x)g'(x)-\lambda_2[f'(x)g(x)-\frac{1}{\lambda_1}\int f(x)g(x)dx]$$

Therefore $$I\left(1-\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}\right)=\lambda_2\left(f(x)g'(x)-f'(x)g(x)\right)$$

Now apply the limits and the required result follows immediately

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: Remark: I think the trick is that when you first do integration by parts, immediately use one of the first two equations for the function that you didn't differentiate. @RajeshDachiraju

Comment: any reason for the downvote?

Answer (score 5):

From the equations
$$\int^1_0f(x)\,dx=\lambda_1\int^1_0f''(x)\,dx=\lambda_1(f'(1)-f'(0))=0\\\int^1_0g(x)\,dx=\lambda_2\int^1_0g''(x)\,dx=\lambda_2(g'(1)-g'(0))=0$$
Thus
$$\int^1_0f(x)g(x)\,dx=\int^x_0f(u)\,du\cdot g(x)\Big|^1_0-\int^1_0g'(x)\int^x_0f(u)\,du\,dx\\=\lambda_1(f'(1)-f'(0))g(1)-\lambda_1\int^1_0g'(x)(f'(x)-f'(0))\,dx\\=-\lambda_1\int^1_0g'(x)(f'(x)-f'(0))\,dx$$
Regarding the last integral 
$$\int^1_0g'(x)(f'(x)-f'(0))\,dx\\=\int^x_0(f'(u)-f'(0))\,du\cdot g'(x)\Big|^1_0-\int^1_0g''(x)\int^x_0(f'(x)-f'(0))\,du\,dx\\=(f(x)-f(0)-xf'(0))g'(x)\Big|^1_0-\int^1_0g''(x)(f(x)-f(0)-xf'(0))\,dx\\=(f(1)-f(0)-f'(0))g'(1)-\int^1_0g''(x)f(x)\,dx+f(0)\int^1_0g''(x)\,dx+f'(0)\int^1_0xg''(x)\,dx\\=-f'(0)g'(1)-\frac{1}{\lambda_2}\int^1_0g(x)f(x)\,dx+f'(0)g'(1)-f'(0)\int^1_0g'(x)\,dx\\=-\frac{1}{\lambda_2}\int^1_0g(x)f(x)\,dx$$
All in all we have
$$\int^1_0f(x)g(x)\,dx=\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2}\int^1_0g(x)f(x)\,dx$$
Since $\lambda_1\neq\lambda_2$ by assumption the claim follows
$$\int^1_0f(x)g(x)\,dx=0$$

Comment: Thanks @Arian Very helpful.